# Map zooms to the current location

Tags: ios, mkmapview, mapkit

After calling the 'startUpdatingLocation' from CLLocation Manager, the map automatically zooms to the current location and animates to that point.

However, I don't want the Map to zoom but remain in the original size. How can I stop this? Please Help.

Answer (score 1):

For example:

```
 mapView.userTrackingMode = MKUserTrackingModeNone;
```

And also

Do not set region `[mapView setRegion:region animated:NO]`; in
`- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)aUserLocation`